# create a related list using batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, batchapexerrorevent

This is the batch class I have created. the execute method is having API call. if I execute this in execute window the related list(order) is not creating.

```
/**
 * Created by mbianca on 01/04/2020.
 */

global class Batch_UpdateProposalStatus implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT ID, CPQ_PaymentId__c, TGLiveSubscribtion__c, TGLiveEquipment__c, Apttus_Proposal__Approval_Stage__c FROM Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c WHERE Apttus_Proposal__Approval_Stage__c = \'Draft\' AND CreatedBy.Name = \'webservice\'';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c> proposalsToManage) {
        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c> proposalsToUpdate = new List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c>();
        for (Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c proposals : proposalsToManage) {
            if ((proposals.CPQ_PaymentId__c != null) && (proposals.TGLiveSubscribtion__c > 0) && (proposals.TGLiveEquipment__c == 0)&& ( proposals.Apttus_Proposal__Approval_Stage__c=='Draft' )) {
               Boolean isSuccess=Apttus_QPConfig.QPConfigWebService.acceptQuote(proposals.id);

            } else {
                proposals.Apttus_Proposal__Approval_Stage__c = 'Signed';
                proposalsToUpdate.add(proposals);
            }
            /* proposals.Apttus_Proposal__Approval_Stage__c = 'Signed';
            proposalsToUpdate.add(proposals); */

        }
        update proposalsToUpdate;




        }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

if I Run directly this code:
`System.debug(Apttus_QPConfig.QPConfigWebService.acceptQuote('a7D0D0000008Vrr'));`

Order is creating. same API i have included in execute method but it is not creating related list

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what happens in Apttus_QPConfig.QPConfigWebService.acceptQuote. The fact that it's inside a loop is a rich source of potential problems - exceeding queries limit, callout limit etc. Is it part of a managed package, or do you have access to see the code?

Comment: That method is managed one.I can't see the code. This API used to accept the proposal and  creating an order.

Comment: Please try to run debug log from the point of executing the batch, see if you get anything suspicious.

Comment: I have executed using Anonymous window. i haven't seen any errors. but it is not updating records

Comment: You won't see any errors in the anonymous Apex log, because it simply executes the batch and that's all. The batch itself runs asynchronously in separate multiple executions contexts. You need to use debug log in order to see what happens in those executions.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that 
`Apttus_QPConfig.QPConfigWebService.acceptQuote('a7D0D0000008Vrr')` is making a callout and that you need to change your batch definition to implement `Database.AllowsCallouts`

Something like

```
global class Batch_UpdateProposalStatus implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowCallouts{
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. but it is not working

Comment: @santhiyadurai What is the error message, how do you run the job, and how many "execute" does it run?